# Trying To Retrieve An Array Element Returns Null

Tags: contract-development, web3js, arrays

This is my contract:

```
contract MessageContract {



   string[] message;
   function setMessage(string _message) public {
       message.push(_message);
   }

   function getMessage(uint i) public constant returns (string) {
       return (message[i]);
   }

}
```

This is my javascript (web3.js):

```
        $("#button").click(function() {

MessageContract.setMessage($("#message").val(),function(){



        });
   });
        $("#button2").click(function() {
        MessageContract.getMessage(0,function(result){
        console.log(result);


    });
    });
```

Every time I try to set the message and try to retrieve the first element of the array, the contract returns null

Comment: Can you check if the message was stored correctly? ie the setMessage didn't run out of gas.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself.

```
MessageContract.getMessage(0,function(error,result){
    console.log(result);


});
```

The result is actually the second parameter of the function.